# If have posts a week old, display, else display a different loop

Tags: wp-query, conditional-content, loop

This is what I have.

```
<?php
$week = date('W');
$year = date('Y');
$projects_in_news = new WP_Query(
                array(
                'post_type' =>'news',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'orderby' =>'ID',
                'order' =>'ASC',
                'w' => $week,
                'y' => $year,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                             'taxonomy' => 'project_taxo',
                             'terms' => $post->post_name,
                             'field' => 'slug'
                             )
                       )
                )
);

// The Loop
<?php if($projects_in_news->have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while($projects_in_news->have_posts()) : $projects_in_news->the_post(); ?>
                <ul class="side-list">     
                    <li>
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <strong class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                            <em class="date"><span><?php the_author(); ?>,</span> <?php the_time('d F Y'); ?></em>
                          </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else: ?>
            <p>There is no news related to this theme</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

What I have here displays posts from the last week that match the query.

Is there a way of determining if this loops query has posts and if not use a different query and loop?

I tried adding the following code in place of `<p>There is no news related to this theme</p>`

```
                                  <?php 
                                            $theme_in_news = new WP_Query(
                                                    array(
                                                        'post_type' =>'theme',
                                                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                                        'orderby' =>'ID',
                                                        'order' =>'ASC',
                                                    )
                                            );
                                    ?>

                                    <?php if($theme_in_news->have_posts()) : ?>

                                    <?php while($theme_in_news->have_posts()) : $theme_in_news->the_post(); ?>
                                    <ul class="side-list">     
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <strong class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                                            <em class="date"><span><?php the_author(); ?>,</span> <?php the_time('d F Y'); ?></em>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But it returns an Internal Server Error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have provided already has a check to see if posts exist for said query. So all you need to do is expand on it.

```
...
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>There is no news related to this theme</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
...
```

Simply place you next query posts in the above code replacing `<p>There is no news related to this theme</p>`

Comment: Hey @Brady. Forgot to mention that I tried that. I placed a new WP Query followed by a loop in place of <p>There is...</p>. The page doesn't load when I do that. It returns an Internal Server Error. Any ideas? Maybe an example will clear things up.

Comment: @Duane please post the code you tried.

Comment: I posted the code above in original question.

Comment: in the second lot of code you have posted you have missed off `<?php endif; ?>`. So you should have two of them one after the other.

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks a million. I can't believe I spent the last two hours trying to figure this out and all I had to do was add another <?php endif; ?> Thanks again @Brady

Comment: @Duane - Don't worry. I've fallen for the same reasons many times before.